# Exporting data from linked list within structure

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I am new to C but working on a project which will retrieve call log information from a database. Before I try and implement this in the real program I am trying to make a test app so that I can make sure the logic is correct just by adding some static data manually into the structure.

The call log will hold the inbound call leg details such as phone number and duration etc and within that structure there is a link listed which contain 1 or more outbound legs.

I appear to be insert the data correctly as far as I can tell from when I step through the code in GDB but the issue I believe is when I try and build up a string to write to a file.

In the export process, it is supposed to loop through the structure, create a string of comma separated values for the inbound leg details, then retrieve each outbound leg from the linked list within the structure and create another string of comma separated values.

Once I have all the legs associated with the inbound leg, I then write these two inbound leg string and outbound leg string to a CSV file.

This is more a less working except for one problem. If the inbound leg has 2 outbound legs, when its written to the file, its only the last outbound leg that is shown, the first outbound leg is not written to the file.

Below is how my structure is defined.

```
typedef struct CallLogStructure
{
    char * date;
    char * time;
    char * bParty;
    char * aParty;
    float duration;
    char * cleardownCause;
    struct Node *outBoundLegs;
} callLogStructure;

typedef struct Node
{
    char * target;
    float targetDuration;
    char * targetCleardownCause;
    struct Node *next;
}node;
```

Below is how I am setting the data for the inbound call and calling the function to insert the outbound legs to the linked list.

```
callLogStructure * callLog = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;
    int dataRow = 0;

    callLog = malloc(dataRow+2 * sizeof(*callLog));
    //start = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs = NULL;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (callLog[0].outBoundLegs == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate RAM\n");
    }
    temp = callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs;
    temp->next = NULL;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs->target = NULL;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs->targetDuration = 0;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs->targetCleardownCause = strdup("0");

    //Insert first inbound leg
    callLog[dataRow].date = "16/05/2011";
    callLog[dataRow].time = "00:00:03";
    callLog[dataRow].aParty = "1234";
    callLog[dataRow].bParty = "5678";
    callLog[dataRow].duration = 0;
    callLog[dataRow].cleardownCause = "unanswered";

    outboundTarget = strdup("4321");
    outboundDuration = 0;
    outboundCleardown = strdup("Unanswered");

    //insertOutBoundLeg(&callLog[0].outBoundLegs, outboundTarget, outboundDuration, outboundCleardown);
    insertOutBoundLeg(callLog, outboundTarget, outboundDuration, outboundCleardown, dataRow);

    //Insert secord inbound
    dataRow++;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs = NULL;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    //temp = callLog[0].outBoundLegs;
    //temp->next = NULL;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs->target = NULL;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs->targetDuration = 0;
    callLog[dataRow].outBoundLegs->targetCleardownCause = strdup("0");

    callLog[dataRow].date = "16/05/2011";
    callLog[dataRow].time = "00:00:58";
    callLog[dataRow].aParty = "6789";
    callLog[dataRow].bParty = "9876";
    callLog[dataRow].duration = 0;
    callLog[dataRow].cleardownCause = "unanswered";

    outboundTarget = strdup("654321");
    outboundDuration = 0;
    outboundCleardown = strdup("unanswered");

    insertOutBoundLeg(callLog, outboundTarget, outboundDuration, outboundCleardown, dataRow);

    outboundTarget = strdup("87654");
    outboundDuration = 10;
    outboundCleardown = strdup("answered");

    insertOutBoundLeg(callLog, outboundTarget, outboundDuration, outboundCleardown, dataRow);
        //printf("NEWLY INSERTED OUTBOUND TARGET: %s", callLog[0].outBoundLegs[0].target);

    writeToFile(callLog, dataRow+1);
```

Below is the function that writes the data to the linked list

```
void insertOutBoundLeg(callLogStructure *callLog, char * target, float targetDuration, char * targetCleardownCause, int callLogIndex)
{
    if (callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->target == NULL)
    {
        printf("INSERTING BRAND NEW OUTBOUND LEG FOR INBOUND\n");
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->target = strdup(target);
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->targetDuration = targetDuration;
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->targetCleardownCause = strdup(targetCleardownCause);
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INSERTING SECOND OR MORE OUTBOUND LEG\n");
        while (callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->next != NULL)
        {
            callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs = callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->next;
        }
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs = callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->next;
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->target = strdup(target);
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->targetDuration = targetDuration;
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->targetCleardownCause = strdup(targetCleardownCause);
        callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

And below is the function that writes the data to the file.

```
void writeToFile(callLogStructure * callLog, int maxRecords)
{
    FILE * myFile;
    myFile = fopen("legs.csv", "wb");
    char * inboundLegFileString = "0";
    char * outboundLegFileString = "0";
    //inboundLegFileString = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    //outboundLegFileString = malloc(sizeof(char *));

    if (callLog == NULL)
    {
        printf("No inbound legs\n");
        return;
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < maxRecords; i++)
    {
        asprintf(&inboundLegFileString, "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%.1f\",\"%s\"",
                callLog[i].date, callLog[i].time, callLog[i].aParty, callLog[i].bParty,
                callLog[i].duration, callLog[i].cleardownCause);

        //printf("Outbound Target: %s\n", callLog[0].outBoundLegs->target);

        while (callLog[i].outBoundLegs != NULL)
        {
            if (callLog[i].outBoundLegs->target != NULL)
            {
                asprintf(&outboundLegFileString, "%s,\"%s\",\"%.1f\",\"%s\"", outboundLegFileString,
                    callLog[i].outBoundLegs->target, callLog[i].outBoundLegs->targetDuration,
                    callLog[i].outBoundLegs->targetCleardownCause);
            }
            callLog[i].outBoundLegs = callLog[i].outBoundLegs->next;
        }
        fprintf(myFile, "%s%s\n", inboundLegFileString, outboundLegFileString);
        inboundLegFileString = "";
        outboundLegFileString = "";
    }
            fclose(myFile);
    return;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've added some more debug within the insert function, so although it looks like I am doing the right thing when I step through it, if I then try and loop through what was inserted right after I still only get the last outbound leg.

Below is what I have added

```
node * outBoundLeg;
    for (outBoundLeg = callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs; outBoundLeg != NULL; outBoundLeg = outBoundLeg->next)
    {
        printf("INSERT: %s\n", outBoundLeg->target);
    }
```

That printf statement is only showing the last outbound target number that was inserted into the list and not the one before so I don't know if I am adding it wrong, or whether I have got the pointers wrong so I am always looking on the end.

Comment: It might be the fact that `asprintf` uses the same destination pointer as one of the arguments, so it may free that buffer (thus invalidating whatever `outboundLegFileString` points to) before "printing" the string. You might need to use a second buffer.

Comment: Don't think it as if I just print the value to the console of the target it only prints the last outbound target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in the *insertOutBoundLeg* function. When you allocate a second outbound leg, you update the root pointer (the *outBoundLegs* member) to point to the new node, thereby losing the first one.

```
callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs = callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs->next;
```

You should be using a temporary pointer to find the last node in the list, and then setting the data for the new node.

So the code for inserting the second leg should look something like this:

```
printf("INSERTING SECOND OR MORE OUTBOUND LEG\n");
struct Node *tempLeg = callLog[callLogIndex].outBoundLegs;
while (tempLeg->next != NULL)
{
    tempLeg = tempLeg->next;
}
tempLeg->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
tempLeg = tempLeg->next;
tempLeg->target = strdup(target);
tempLeg->targetDuration = targetDuration;
tempLeg->targetCleardownCause = strdup(targetCleardownCause);
tempLeg->next = NULL;
```

Another problem is in your *writeToFile* function. You initialise the output strings with "0" which almost certainly isn't what you want.

```
char * inboundLegFileString = "0";
char * outboundLegFileString = "0";
```

Assumedly that should be:

```
char * inboundLegFileString = "";
char * outboundLegFileString = "";
```

Otherwise you are going to have an unwanted zero between the inbound and outbound legs in the csv.

I would also suggest you consider updating the *writeToFile* function to use temporary pointers when traversing the outbound legs, because it has the same problem as the *insertOutBoundLegs* function. You are overwriting your root pointer (the *outBoundLegs* member) again.

```
callLog[i].outBoundLegs = callLog[i].outBoundLegs->next;
```

The code works, but it will only work once.

Finally, I should mention that you are making unnecessary calls to *strdup* when initialising the *outboundTarget* and *outboundCleardown* variables before calling *insertOutBoundLeg*.

```
outboundTarget = strdup("4321");           // this strdup not needed
outboundDuration = 0;
outboundCleardown = strdup("Unanswered");  // this strdup not needed
```

The *insertOutBoundLeg* function is going to *strdup* those parameters anyway, so the strings just end up being duplicated twice, which is likely to result in a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. You are right I was updating the pointer so done everything you suggested and is working as expected